# Getting scipy.cKDTree to return everything with a given meter radius

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, scipy, scipy.spatial, scikit-learn

I want to find everything within a 0.1 meter radius.
I'm confused on exactly how `query_ball_point` is getting distance. I'm using decimal degree coordinates when creating the cKDTree, ie. `[(-73.52610659993773, 40.99738620279574), (-73.52610659993992, 40.99738620279341), etc]`.

This currently works in my real life use cases but it was just testing different numbers until it did. I read the [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) documentation and I'm having a hard time understanding how it's getting the distance and how different units come into play. I feel like I might be overthinking this but was hoping someone could give some clarity for someone with no understanding of geography.

```
new_tree = spatial.cKDTree(decimal_degree_coords)
found_points = new_tree.query_ball_point(check_feature, .00001)
```

Answer (score 2):

These coordinates are in decimal degrees. Therefore, you must calculate the decimal degree equivalent of 0.1 meter on Earth. If we assume the radius of Earth is `6370 km`, then `0.1 m`  approximately equals to `0.0000009` degree.

```
found_points = new_tree.query_ball_point(check_feature, .0000009)
```

Comment: How do we know it's calculated in decimal degrees? Or wait the classification doesn't matter right? It's just numbers and it's just doing pythagorean theorem between two numbers. So it's just the relative difference between the two that matters and then converting that relation into what would be the meter equivalent.

Comment: @HeardEmSay I don't think it's calculated in decimal degrees. As you said, they are just numbers. All calculations must be performing  in Cartesian plane. Therefore, I've recommended you to use the degree equivalent of 0.1 m. Otherwise (transforming the coordinates from degree to a projected plane) it could be worse. That is all I can say since I don't know about your data. But in this scale (we are talking about 0.1 m), that is the only solution I can think of. I wish One offer a sophisticated solution.